# Getting JDK error while installing anything

Tags: jdk

I tried to install git and android studio but following error showed while installing. Please do help.

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
jdk1.8.0-77
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
saurav@lappy:~$ java -version
java version "1.5.0"
gij (GNU libgcj) version 4.8.4**
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try updating Java files on the system?

Use the below commands to see if any updates are available.

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade